# numpy precision with large numbers

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

I want to factorize a large number using Fermat's factorization method. This is how I implemented it:

```
import numpy as np

def fac(n):
    x = np.ceil(np.sqrt(n))
    y = x*x - n
    while not np.sqrt(y).is_integer():
        x += 1
        y = x*x - n
    return(x + np.sqrt(y), x - np.sqrt(y))
```

Using this method I want to factor `N` into its components. Note that `N=p*q`, where `p` and `q` are prime.

I chose the following values to compute `N`:

```
p = 34058934059834598495823984675767545695711020949846845989934523432842834738974239847294083409583495898523872347284789757987987387543533846141.0
q = 34058934059834598495823984675767545695711020949846845989934523432842834738974239847294083409583495898523872347284789757987987387543533845933.0
```

and defined `N`

```
N = p*q
```

Now I factor N:

```
r = fac(n)
```

However, the factorization seems to not be correct:

```
int(r[0])*int(r[1]) == N
```

It does work for smaller ints:

```
fac(65537)
Out[1]: (65537.0, 1.0)
```

I'm quite sure the reason is numerical precision at some point.

I tried calculating N in numpy using object types:

```
N = np.dot(np.array(p).astype(object), np.array(q).astype(object))
```

but it doesn't help. Still, the numpy requires a float for the `sqrt` function.

I also tried using the `math` library instead of numpy, this library seems to not require a float for its sqrt function, but ultimately running into precision issues as well.

Comment: your `p` is float, why would you do factorization with float values? You should work with intergers to utilize the unbound int size. Also, use some other way to compute (integer) square root, not `np.sqrt` since that casts your number to float.

Comment: @QuangHoang the reason I use floats is exactly because np.sqrt requires it. What would be the alternative?

Comment: use binary search to compute the (ceiling of) square root... `is_integer` can be replaced with `sqrt = binary_search_sqrt(x); if sqrt*sqrt == x: do_something`.

Comment: Those numbers are way too big to fit any of NumPy's types. Why not use Python integers, which have unbounded precision? If you have Python 3.8 or later, `math.isqrt` provides an integer square root.

Comment: Or put more clearly: NumPy's floats have a binary precision of 53 bits. The highest precision integer type commonly available in NumPy has 64 bits of precision. Your `N` needs 928 bits of precision to represent exactly. NumPy is simply the wrong tool for the job here (as is floating-point).

Comment: For arbitrary precision floats, consider the `mpmath` library.

Answer (score 3):

Python int are multiple precision numbers. But numpy is a wrapper around C low level libraries to speed up operations. The downside is that it cannot handle those multi-precision numbers. Worse, if you try to use `np.sqrt` on them, they will be converted to floating point numbers (C double or numpy float64) what have a precision of about 15 decimal digits.

But as Python int type is already a multiprecision type, you could use `math.sqrt` to get an approximative value of the true square root, and then use Newton to find a closer value:

```
def isqrt(n):
    x = int(math.sqrt(n))
    old = None
    while True:
        d = (n - x * x) // (2 * x)
        if d == 0: break
        if d == 1:                 # infinite loop prevention
            if old is None:
                old = 1
            else: break
        x += d
    return x
```

Using it, your `fac` function could become:

```
def fac(n):
    x = isqrt(n)
    if x*x < n: x += 1
    y = x * x - n
    while True:
        z = isqrt(y)
        if z*z == y: break
        x += 1
        y = x*x -n
    return x+z, x-z
```

Demo:

```
p = 34058934059834598495823984675767545695711020949846845989934523432842834738974239847294083409583495898523872347284789757987987387543533846141
q = 34058934059834598495823984675767545695711020949846845989934523432842834738974239847294083409583495898523872347284789757987987387543533845933
N = p*q
print(fac(N) == (p,q))
```

prints as expected `True`

Comment: Note that as of Python 3.8, there's an `isqrt` function in the `math` module already.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Look like I should upgrade my 3.7 version then...

Comment: @MarkDickinson: No nitpicking here, it was indeed a flaw in my code. Thanks to your comment, it is now fixed